# How to initialize an array by default in a single row C#?

Tags: c#

I have this line of code and I want under certain conditions to initialize the whole array to true in one line,
How can I do that?

```
public bool[,] OptionalHours { get; set; } = new bool[6, 24];
```

Comment: Why one line? You'll need 2 loops. Or maybe 1 if you want to do clever math.

Comment: How can i do it with 1 loop?

Comment: @N.A why are you focusing on lines of code and number of (separate) loops?  You should write the code that is easiest to read later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, this would do it:

```
for(int i = 0, x = _optionalHours.GetLength(0), y = _optionalHours.GetLength(1); i < x * y; _optionalHours[i/y, i%y] = true, i++);
```

It gets shorter if you're happy to fix the 6 and 24 and jiggle some ops around:

```
for(int i = 6*24; --i >= 0; _optionalHours[i/24, i%24] = true);
```

Would you use it though? Well; could you understand it immediately and are happy to explain it to anyone else who asks? If yes, then use it. If no then go for something more expected:

```
for(int x = _optionalHours.GetUpperBound(0); x >= 0; x--)
  for(int y = _optionalHours.GetUpperBound(1); y >= 0; y--)
    _optionalHours[x, y] = true;
```

There aren't any prizes at code review for the person who wrote the most WTF..

---

It's also quite a small array (hours in a week?) so you could also init it with this one-liner that's easier to figure:

```
   var _optionalHours = new[,]{
        {true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
        {true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
        {true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
        {true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
        {true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
        {true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true}
    };
```

---

As an idle curiosity, you could also do it "mathematically", wrap the array in a class that will invert the bools if some condition is set:

```
public class SixByTwentyFour
{
    private bool[,] _optionalHours { get; set; } = new bool[6, 24];
    public bool CertainCondition; 
    
    public bool this[int x, int y]{
      get => _optionalHours[x,y] ^ CertainCondition;
      set { _optionalHours[x,y] = value ^ CertainCondition; }
    }
}
```

You can access an instance of this class as though it were a 2D array:

```
var sbtf = new SixByTwentyFour();

sbtf.CertainCondition = true;

Console.WriteLine(sbtf[1,1]); //prints true
```

This one doesn't give you a "Properties should not return arrays" warning if you have an analayzer enabled that looks for such :D

Comment: The first example is really clear and short thank you very much...